# Can I use “wheel” instead of “switch”?

Tags: meaning

In Longman Dictionary, under 'asleep at the wheel/switch', it says that

asleep at the wheel/switch:
not paying attention to a situation, so that something bad happens

• Several publishers were asleep at the switch, and missed the book’s potential.

Then.. can I use “wheel” instead of “switch”? Are they actually the same?

1. Several publishers were asleep at the (switch), and missed the book’s potential.
2. Several publishers were asleep at the (wheel), and missed the book’s potential. *Not literal

Comment: They are both metaphors, so it doesn't matter which you use. You could also use *rudder*, *controls*, *helm*, and so on.